# Replacing value with value in a second file

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have two files. Both files are a TXT.

File one contains strings, one per line.

File two contains some text.

File two looks like this:

```
 title:
  VALUE:
    display_name: VALUE
    resource:
      material: material
      generate: false
      model_path: model/VALUE
 title:
  VALUE:
    display_name: VALUE
    resource:
      material: material
      generate: false
      model_path: model/VALUE
```

File one like this:

```
einundzwanzig
dreiundzwanzig
vierundzwanzig
fuenfundzwanzig
```

My intention is, that VALUE gets replaced with the string in line one, for three times. Then for the next three VALUEs the second string. And so on. I tried to get it done by using bash, but it doesn't work out.

So I tried following script:

```
    count=1
# filetwo.txt is your file
cat test.xml | tr "\n" "\t" > test2.xml
while read line
do
    echo $count
    echo $line
    sed -i " s_value[^<]*value_value$linevalue_${count}; " fileone.txt
    ((count++))
done < filetwo.txt
cat test2.xml | tr "\t" "\n" >fileoutput.txt
```

But it does not want to work :(

Comment: `<value>` what do these html tags do in your source?

Comment: I originally tried to use them for an XML file but switched to txt

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: You can't parse xml with regex - that's impossible. To edit xml use xml aware tools, not `sed`. And your file looks like a yaml file. Note that your `sed -i` will _each time_ replace the value. So the next time you run it, the count is wrong, because the first one was already replaced. With your method you would want to replace first VALUE always.

Comment: what happens if the number of `VALUE` strings is more than three times the numberof replacement values?

Comment: what are the `cat text*.xml` commands supposed to be doing (ie, what do these have to do with the requirement to replace the `VALUE` strings)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- we are looking to replace the literal strings `VALUE`
- the literal string `VALUE` does not show up in a longer string (eg, `DEVALUE`)
- the number of `VALUE` strings is less than (or equal) to three times the number of replacement strings (ie, we won't run out of replacement strings)

Input files:

```
$ cat value.template
 title:
  VALUE:
    display_name: VALUE
    resource:
      material: material
      generate: false
      model_path: model/VALUE
 title:
  VALUE:
    display_name: VALUE
    resource:
      material: material
      generate: false
      model_path: model/VALUE
 title:
  VALUE:
    display_name: VALUE
      model_path: model/VALUE
 title:
  VALUE:
    display_name: VALUE
      model_path: model/VALUE

$ cat value.dat
einundzwanzig
dreiundzwanzig
vierundzwanzig
fuenfundzwanzig
```

One `awk` solution:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { i=1 }                                    # initialize our array counter

# process first file (NR==FNR)

NR==FNR { v[i++]=v[i++]=v[i++]=$1 ; next }         # save the replacement string in next 3 array slots

# process second file

FNR==1  { i=1 }                                    # for first line of 2nd file, reset our array counter
/VALUE/ { while ( sub("VALUE",v[i]) ) { i++ } }    # if line includes "VALUE" string then replace each occurrence with next array element referenced by "i"; increment i for next sub()/match
        { print }                                  # print current line
' value.dat value.template
```

A different `awk` solution that stores the replacement strings just once in the `v[]` array:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { i=0 }                                              # initialize array counter
NR==FNR { v[i++]=$1 ; next }                                 # save the replacement string in next array slot
FNR==1  { i=1 }                                              # for first line of 2nd file, reset our array counter
/VALUE/ { while ( sub("VALUE",v[int((i-1)/3)]) ) { i++ } }   # for every 3 instances of "VALUE" replace with the same entry from the v[] array; increment i after each sub()/match
        { print }                                            # print current line
' value.dat value.template
```

**NOTE**: Remove comments to declutter code

Both of the above generate:

```
 title:
  einundzwanzig:
    display_name: einundzwanzig
    resource:
      material: material
      generate: false
      model_path: model/einundzwanzig
 title:
  dreiundzwanzig:
    display_name: dreiundzwanzig
    resource:
      material: material
      generate: false
      model_path: model/dreiundzwanzig
 title:
  vierundzwanzig:
    display_name: vierundzwanzig
      model_path: model/vierundzwanzig
 title:
  fuenfundzwanzig:
    display_name: fuenfundzwanzig
      model_path: model/fuenfundzwanzig
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -Ee '1{x;s/^/cat file1/e;x}                     # copy file1 to hold space
         :a;/title:/{                               # when line contains title:
           :b;n;/title:/{x;s/^[^\n]*\n//;x;ba}      # end of stanza reduce file1
           /VALUE/{G;s/VALUE([^\n]*)\n(\S+).*/\2\1/} # replace VALUE 
         bb}' file2                                 # repeat
```

On line one, copy the contents of file1 into the hold space.

If a line contains `title:` print that line and fetch the next.

If that line contains `title`, remove the first line of file1 in the hold space and repeat from loop holder `:a`.

Otherwise, if the current line contains `VALUE`, append the hold space to the current line and replace `VALUE` by the first line in the hold space.

Repeat from loop holder `:b`.

Alternative, just replace 3 `VALUE` fields in file2 for each line in file1:

```
sed -E '1{x;s/^/sed "p;p" file1/e;x}
        :a;/VALUE/{G;s/VALUE([^\n]*)\n(\S+).*/\2\1/;x;s/[^\n]*\n//;x;ba}' file2
```